# How to simply rotate SCNNode in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a live data stream from a gyro sensor which I want to mirror in a simple object in SceneKit.

This is the class declaration and how I read the data (mostly for context):

```
class GraphicsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var newView: SCNView!
var device: MetaWear!
let geometry:SCNGeometry = SCNPyramid(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1)
var graphicsScene: SCNScene!
var cameraNode: SCNNode!
var pyramidNode:SCNNode
(...)

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.pyramidNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    pyramidNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    (...)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.updateLabel("Restoring")
        if let state = DeviceState.loadForDevice(device) {
            // Initialize the device
            device.deserialize(state.serializedState)
            self.updateLabel("Connecting")
            device.connectAndSetup().continueWith { t in
                if let error = t.error {
                    // Sorry we couldn't connect
                    print("ERROR: Could not connect!")
                } else {
                    // The result of a connectAndSetup call is a task which completes upon disconnection.
                    t.result!.continueWith {
                        state.serializedState = self.device.serialize()
                        state.saveToUrl(self.device.uniqueUrl)
                        self.updateLabel($0.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Disconnected")
                    }

                    self.updateLabel("Connected")
                    self.device.flashLED(color: .green, intensity: 1.0, _repeat: 3)
                    self.magnetoTest()
                    print("passed magneto test")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All is well so far. The magnitoTest function looks like this:

```
func magnetoTest(){
        mbl_mw_mag_bmm150_set_preset(device.board, MBL_MW_MAG_BMM150_PRESET_LOW_POWER);
        mbl_mw_sensor_fusion_write_config(device!.board)

        let gyroData = mbl_mw_mag_bmm150_get_b_field_data_signal(device.board)

        mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(gyroData!, bridge(obj: self)) { (context, data) in
            let dataSignal = data!.pointee.valueAs() as MblMwCartesianFloat
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                print(dataSignal.z)
                let mySelf = Unmanaged<GraphicsViewController>.fromOpaque(context!).takeUnretainedValue()
                mySelf.pyramidNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: dataSignal.x, y: dataSignal.y, z: dataSignal.z, w: Float(10.0))
                mySelf.testData = SCNVector3(x: dataSignal.x, y: dataSignal.y, z: dataSignal.z)
            }
        }
        mbl_mw_mag_bmm150_enable_b_field_sampling(device.board);
        mbl_mw_mag_bmm150_start(device.board)
    }
```

I expected mySelf.PyramidNode.Rotation to work, but it doesn't. Observing changes to the data does nothing as well:

```
var testData:SCNVector3? {
        willSet(newValue) {
            print("About to set new data: \(newValue)")
            pyramidNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(newValue!.x, newValue!.y, newValue!.z, 0.0)
            //pyramidNode.position = newValue!
            print("new rotation: \(pyramidNode.rotation)")

            let rotationAction =   SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(1.0), around: SCNVector3(3,5,0), duration: 2.0)
            pyramidNode.runAction(rotationAction)
            cameraNode.runAction(rotationAction)

            cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(newValue!.x, newValue!.y, newValue!.z, 0.0)
            cameraNode.position = newValue!
        }
        didSet(val) {
            print("data was set! \(val)")
        }
    }
```

The result of this is nothing. No errors, not warnings, and no changes to the pyramid node. This is the print output from the top:

```
    2019-02-18 01:04:23.446607+0100 StarterProject[4001:2128327] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful 2019-02-18
     01:04:23.726821+0100 StarterProject[4001:2128243] [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBCentralManager: 0x283ad59c0> has no restore identifier but the delegate implements the centralManager:willRestoreState: method. Restoring will not be supported 
    MainTableViewCtrl says hello to 0 devices 
    AppDelegate says hello 
    ScanTableViewCtrl says hello 
    MainTableViewCtrl says hello to 1 devices 
    2019-02-18 01:04:29.952980+0100 StarterProject[4001:2128243] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled 2019-02-18 01:04:29.956667+0100 StarterProject[4001:2128243] Metal API Validation Enabled 
graphics says hello 
Restoring 
Connecting 
Connected 
passed magneto test
About to set new data: Optional(__C.SCNVector3(x: 25.875, y: 74.4375, z: 5.1875)) 
new rotation: SCNVector4(x: 25.875, y: 74.4375, z: 5.1875, w: 0.0) 
data was set! nil
About to set new data: Optional(__C.SCNVector3(x: 25.5, y: 75.875, z: 5.9375)) 
new rotation: SCNVector4(x: 25.5, y: 75.875, z: 5.9375, w: 0.0) 
data was set! Optional(__C.SCNVector3(x: 25.875, y: 74.4375, z: 5.1875))
About to set new data: Optional(__C.SCNVector3(x: 26.25, y: 77.0, z: 4.8125)) 
new rotation: SCNVector4(x: 26.25, y: 77.0, z: 4.8125, w: 0.0) 
data was set! Optional(__C.SCNVector3(x: 25.5, y: 75.875, z: 5.9375))
```

All this seems to work, but it doesn't affect change in the pyramid in my Scene. As you can tell, I've tried moving both the camera and the pyramid in several ways (more than shown).

In summary, I get live data (fast), from a sensor. I want to mirror the orientation of the sensor in a object in a SceneKit Scene. I got the data and I have the object, but I cannot figure out how to apply the data to the object's rotation.

I simply don't understand why my changes to the rotation of the pyramid (or camera), doesn't change anything in the app. Even hardcoded values does nothing to shift the view of the pyramid.

Hope you can help, any tips and hints is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Newbie that I am, I added the geometry to the scene, rather than the node itself.

Sorry for wasting your time.